# Community Evaluation Results - #2, February 2013

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

Since Stack Exchange doesn't support tables ([hint hint wink wink nudge nudge knowwhatImean knowwhatImean](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT3_UCm1A5I)), you can click the following link to obtain the...

## [Community Evaluation Results for February 2013.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvvihYwat4zDdEhTYXJnZm5wZjJ5QkFZTDFNTTM4bVE#gid=0)

Please answer with whatever SCIENCE you can extrapolate from this data.

---

[← Previous community evaluation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4425/23)

Comment: Best result: about 117 people took part in the review!

Comment: FYI: we have disabled these evaluations on non-beta sites going forward, though we super appreciate everyone who has participated so far and showed us that we have little to worry about with graduated sites. If you want to run one of these again, let us know and we can provide you a set of questions to use if you want.

Answer (score 5):

[image: enter link description here]

- **40%** of the votes are Excellent
- **50%** of the votes are Satisfactory
- **11%** of the votes are Needs Improvement
- That doesn't sum up to 100%. Yay rounding.

Extrapolating wildly, we could say that while we only provide content above what the rest of the world does 40% of the time, visiting us is only "a waste of time" 11% of the time; 9 times out of 10 we'll present good information in a good manner thanks to the Stack Exchange engine and our voting.

Comment: It's OK to use decimal places.  I promise.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot _or_ I could round even further to 40/50/10!

Answer (score 2):

[image: enter link description here]

Do we reward original research, good presentation and excellence in answering while downvoting answers that need improvements? Yes... marginally.

Now, while the curve isn't quite as steep as I'd like to see, it would've also been concerning if it was *too* steep. Voting is supposed to show the quality of a post, not the quality of a post compared to what's out there on the rest of the internet. All of these post scores are rather low and tag popularity certainly plays a role here (*cough* Hyperdimension Neptunia 2 *cough*).

If we just look at review score vs post score, we get [a similar story.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/modcP.png)

Comment: Wow.. Honestly this range of plots to me just makes it seem if anything we are biased to games we like/play, which you do touch on a bit, as opposed to just generally rewarding what are possibly good or penalizing bad answers. Can always hide behind 'but I do not know this game' I guess but this does seem a bit odd to me... I have always wondered about questions with 1000's of views but only a few up votes... and likewise questions with only a couple of up votes while its answer has multiple votes. If the answer is that outstanding or often asked it would seem to me worth a +1 or so.

Comment: @James Well, we do have more Guild Wars 2 players than we have for Dungeon Crawl players or Football Manager 2013. Minecraft and Starcraft 2 are one of our main games and they sit in the middle.

Comment: A single question doesn't represent all questions about a game. Labeling the points on the chart with the game they're tagged as is severely misleading, IMO.

Comment: @grant the alternative was writing the whole question title